# Need help in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have DB table below:

```
TaskId StartDate   TargetEnd  TaskStatus
1      2011-01-01  2011-02-05 completed
2      2011-02-05  2011-02-05 ongoing
3      2011-02-04  2011-04-04 completed
4      2011-04-04  2011-04-04 completed
5      2011-04-06  2011-04-30 ongoing
```

I created a query where i can get the total completed and ongoing tasks per month:

```
SELECT YEAR(TargetEnd) 'YEAR',
  MONTHNAME(TargetEnd) 'MONTH',
  SUM(IF(TaskStatus = 'ongoing',1,0)) 'ONGOING',
  SUM(IF(TaskStatus = 'completed',1,0)) 'COMPLETED',
  COUNT(TaskId) 'TOTAL' FROM Task_Table GROUP BY YEAR(TargetEnd), MONTH(TargetEnd)
```

and the result is:

```
   YEAR  MONTH    ONGOING COMPLETED TOTAL
   2011  January   0        1        1
   2011  February  0        1        2
   2011  April     1        2        3
```

But my requirement is to add task #2 as part of `ONGOING` while task is still "ongoing" from the `TargetEnd` month up to the current month(February- April). The expected should be like this:

```
   YEAR  MONTH    ONGOING COMPLETED TOTAL
   2011  January   0        0        0
   2011  February  1        1        1
   2011  March     1        0        1
   2011  April     2        2        4
```

Can you give me an idea on how can I accomplish this? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

---

I edited the expected result above. There should have been no count for January as the count is solely based on the **TargetEnd**'s month.

Comment: It may just be me, but could you give examples of how you wish each input record to be treated, and thus how it feeds in to the final example result you have given?

Comment: I think you're going to have to, instead of searching through the months represented in the table, search from the _first_ month represented in the table until `NOW()`, and do a bunch of joins comparing various values in each row w.r.t. the month being iterated.

Answer (score 1):

If I uderstand correctly...
- If a record shows as Completed, it needs to contribute 1 to the `completed` value, and only for the month in which it completed.
- If a record shows as Ongoing, it needs to contribute 1 to the `ongoing` value, for every month since it started.

The first issue that you have is that the month March, therefore doesn't have an equivilent record in the input data.  My preferred way of dealing with that is to create a lookup table of months.

```
SELECT
  lookup.month,
  SUM(CASE WHEN task_table.TaskStatus = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN task_table.TaskStatus = 'Ongoing'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed,
  COUNT(task_table.TaskStatus) AS total
FROM
  lookup
LEFT JOIN
  task_table
    ON
    (
      task_table.TaskStatus = 'Completed'
      AND lookup.month <= task_table.Target_End
      AND lookup.month >  task_table.Target_End - INTERVAL '1 month'
    )
    OR
    (
      task_table.TaskStatus = 'Ongoing'
      AND lookup.month <= task_table.Target_End
      AND lookup.month >  task_table.Start_Date - INTERVAL '1 month'
    )
WHERE
      lookup.month >= '2011-01-01'
  AND lookup.month <= '2011-04-01'
GROUP BY
  lookup.month
```

Comment: You got it right. If a record is completed, it will only have 1 count on the **TargetEnd** month. I will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot for taking your time sharing your idea.

Comment: I still cant figure out how to get the expected result based on your suggestion. :(

Comment: I think you still need to give spefic details of how each input record reclates to your suggested output.